# Why does this jQuery AJAX loop fail with a 400 error after hundreds of successful loops?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loops

I've written the code below which uses a `$csv_rows` array from PHP as data to be imported, each row is AJAXed and saved to the database. We've noticed it will 400 error at around 500+ rows (sometimes 1000+).

I've checked the network tab in Chrome debugger while the import is happening and there is no issue with the data being passed at the time of the error (the data shown is in the same format as previous rows which were successful).

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {

    try {

        var csvRows = $.parseJSON( '<?php echo json_encode( $csv_rows ); ?>' );

    } catch( error ) {

        alert(error);

    }

    var totalRows = csvRows.length - 1;
    var rowsRemaining = csvRows.length - 1;
    var rowsDone = 0;

    function doAjax( $row ) {

        // AJAX

        var data = {
            'action': 'import',
            'row': csvRows[row],
        };

        // Do the ajax

        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            success: function( response ) {

                console.log( reseponse );

            }
        }).done( function() {

            row = row + 1;

            if ( row <= totalRows ) {

                doAjax( row );

            } else {

                alert('Import complete');

            }

            rowsRemaining = rowsRemaining - 1;
            rowsDone = rowsDone + 1;

        }).fail( function( xhr, error, status ) {

            alert( status );

        });

    }

    row = 0;

    doAjax( row );

});
```

Comment: I would say that part of the answer is stated in the question : look at what happens on the PHP side (server logs, debugging ...)

Comment: @LeGEC the only thing that looks related in the server logs is a bunch of lines like this "[18-Aug-2020 15:16:24] WARNING: child 47650 said into stderr: "Tue Aug 18 15:16:24 2020 (47650): Warning Not enough free shared space to allocate 126 bytes (8 bytes free)" - although this is coming from other functions within the website not the one referenced in the code above

Comment: you see the 400 error in the `alert(status)` on ajax failure, correct ?

Comment: If yes : this means the 400 error is returned by the server. Check the access logs, for example, to confirm the answer was returned with a 400 code.

Comment: @LeGEC the alert is blank, if i look in the Network tab of the debugger the red ajax request is showing as 400.

Comment: ok, this still means that the error occured before reaching the navigator

Comment: Is the PHP app an application written by your team ? or is it an external product ?

Comment: @legec The PHP element of this is a function we've written that updates a product's price and stock from the data in the CSV, we aren't seeing anything in the error log related to that function, the only thing in the logs that looks odd is the Not enough free shared space commented earlier :/

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs on the server side, so you will need to debug the server.

Since you mention PHP code, I assume it is served through a server like apache or nginx : check in the *access* log of this server if you see requests to your route which are answered with a `400` response code.

- if you see them : you can debug the apache/nginx configuration and your PHP code
- if you don't : the error happens between your own server and the browser, check other elements : are any proxies involved ? does your hoster have another service in front of your apache/nginx ? ...